# How to log daily changes in Linux Filesystem?

Tags: linux, filesystems, daemon

Can anyone please suggest me some script or mechanism so that I can record all the Changes made into my GNU/Linux File System on daily basis.

Example:

Suppose I make the following changes on 1-Jan-2012:

```
File_Modified                Modification_type      Date/Timestamp

/mnt/linux_d/notes.txt       Added                  1-Jan-2012 10:00 AM

/root/Desktop/log/pdf        Deleted                1-Jan-2012 2:00 PM

/root/Document/sample.html   Modified               1-Jan-2012 5:00 PM
```

Thanks.

Best Regards,

Sandeep Singh

Comment: Are you really sure you want to log all changes? It could make a huge logfile!

Comment: Yes, I am looking for some command-line option (preferably) rather than going for a scanner. This will also enable me to run it on a particular directory rather than going for entire "/" partition.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at **tripwire**:

> Tripwire is a tool that aids system administrators and users in
>   monitoring a designated set of files for any changes. Used with system
>   files on a regular (e.g., daily) basis, Tripwire can notify system
>   administrators of corrupted or tampered files, so damage control
>   measures can be taken in a timely manner.

There are packages available on many distributions.

Answer (score 2):

`zfs` file system supports similar functionality. And there are many more. See this wiki entry. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versioning_file_system

Answer (score 2):

If you care only about changes inside one single directory, you could use the [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) facilities, in particular [inotifywatch](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywatch).

You can also use `incrond` thru [incrontab](http://linux.die.net/man/5/incrontab)